# How can the Full Arsenal achievement in FTL be achieved?

Tags: achievements, ftl-faster-than-light

The Full Arsenal achievement in FTL says you need 11 systems installed on a Kestral at one time.

So what counts as a system to do this? Augmentations? Weapons? Drones? Those seem to add to only nine possible. What else could you add?

Oh, I guess there is Cloaking Device and Teleporter... that could add to eleven if the weapons and drones count - do they? Is there something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anything that's labeled as a system or subsystem in the upgrade screen. 
[image: Pretty much anything in there]

8 systems, 4 subsystems. Before the expansion, there was only 3 subsystems (no battery pack) and only 3 available systems to add (cloaking/drones/teleporter, no mind control/hacking)

Answer (score 2):

Full Arsenal requires 8 systems (rooms which require power) and 3 subsystems (rooms which don't- the Kestral already has three).

You already begin with five systems and three subsystems, so you need three of the following:

- Teleporter
- Drone Bay
- Mind Control
- Hacking
- Cloaking